# What is the use of XML?

Tags: xml

I'm new to XML and the thing is, I don't see the point of using XML and XML files. mostly, XML is being used for static data, and I don't know how it differs from JSON or classes, or even databases (in case of a parent tag that contains identical child tags). as far as I know,  XML seems to be useless.

the thing is, I see XML wildly used. I must conclude that there is useability to XML, which is hidden for me.

what is XML used for in "real - life" projects? and what abilities it has that other tools (such as JSON, classes, and databases) don't have?

Comment: XML was created in 1996, JSON in 2006. Both are used for similar purposes. You usually see XML in things made before 2006 (Collada, SVG, DOCX, XMP, RSS, Atom ...), or if authors liked XML and were a bit lazy to switch to JSON.

Comment: @IvanKuckir so is it just "old JSON"? do you recommend me not to learn it?

Comment: You should know the basics (tags, attributes, comments, tree syntax), but I don't recommend "going deep" into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call it useless. **XML** is much easier option for many applications. We don't use is the "real - life" projects where size of data is **large** and where we have to do **frequent transactions**. But we use it in those situations like when we need to store **small amount of data** or to communicate with one node of network to other node. Here are some other resources i found:

1. [Uses of xml - w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/xml/uses-of-xml.php)
2. [Uses Of XML- IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzamj/rzamjintrouses.htm)